# SSRS Report Parameters With Default Values Not get called in Report Manager only

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I have an ssrs report with multiple cascading paramters, there is a parameter called Items, dataset of this parameter accepts 7 parameters, but I have given default values to these seven parameters in SQL, and handled nulls as well, so it does not needs any single parameters to return results.

I also set this dataset as my parameters default value, now the behavior I want is that when the report loads, it should show data without any filtration, and as user selects values from other seven parameters, it updates itself accordingly.

I can successfully see the desired behavior in visual studio dev environment, but when I deploy same report, in report manager, it does not loads unless I select all seven levels.

I tried deleting report from report manager and deploy again, but same result.

What I could be missing ?

Comment: I am also trying to get a report to load with default parameters, then allow the user to select parameters provided by a query after the report is loaded. Did you find a solution for this?